# Does rightsizing a vm instance in google cloud reset its content?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-instances

In my vm instance dashboard there's written that by rightsizing the vm instance cpu i could save some money.
My question is if doing so will erase the memory in the vm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the memory will be erased because the VM must be shut down first.